# Why does my React material-ui Grid not take up full height of the screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, material-ui, chart.js

I have built a material-ui drawer component for the navigation and using material-ui grid to place my chart.js graph inside. However the graph/grid does not take up the full height even though I have specified height 100% in Grid.js, there is still white space at the bottom.

I want the grid with the chart in to take up full height of the screen and leave no white space.

Picture below:

[image]

code:

Grid.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Grid, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
import Chart3 from '../Components/Chart/Chart3';
import ChartStream from '../Components/Chart/ChartStream';
import Table from '../Components/Table/Table';





const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    grid: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        margin: '0px'
    },
    paper: {
        padding: theme.spacing(2),
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: theme.palette.text.seconday,
        background: theme.palette.success.light,
    }

}));


function Grido() {
    const classes = useStyles();
  return (
      <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.grid}  >
          <Grid item xs={12} md={12}>
              <Chart3 />
          </Grid>
      </Grid>

   
  );
}

export default Grido;
```

App2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import './App.css'

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch, Route, Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Drawer, List, ListItem,
  ListItemIcon, ListItemText,
  Container, Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import HomeIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Home";
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';
import Grido from './Grid/Grid';
import Footer from './Components/Footer/Footer';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  drawerPaper: { width: 'inherit', height: '100%', background: '#F7F5FB' },
  link: {
    textDecoration: 'none',
    color: theme.palette.text.primary
  }
}))

const styles = {
  paper: {
    background: "blue"
  }
}

function App2() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Router>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        <Drawer
          style={{ width: '220px' }}
          classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
          variant="persistent"
          anchor="left"
          open={true}
          classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}
        >
          <List>
            <Link to="/" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <HomeIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"Home"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/about" className={classes.link}>
              <ListItem button>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <InfoIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={"About"} />
              </ListItem>
            </Link>
          </List>
        </Drawer>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Container>
                <Grido />
            </Container>
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/about">
            <Container>
              <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom>
                About
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body1" gutterBottom>
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
              </Typography>
            </Container>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App2;
```

chart3.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import axios from "axios";
import './Chart.css';

const Chart3 = () => {
    //Setting states for later use
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  const [Forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);
  const [Actual, setActual] = useState([]);

  const chart = () => {
      //Setting up variables to store data
    let Fore = [];
    let Act = [];

    //Using Axios to get the data from api
    axios
      .get('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity/2020-09-01T15:30Z/2020-09-10T17:00Z')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
          Fore.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.forecast));
          Act.push(parseInt(dataObj.intensity.actual));
        }
        //Now setting chart data now we have the data from API and parsed it 
        setChartData({
          labels: Fore,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Carbon Intensity Levels",
              data: Act,
              backgroundColor: "#F58A07",
              borderWidth: 4
            }
          ]
        });
      })
      //Catching an error for when recieving API data
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(Fore, Act);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1></h1>
      <div className="chart">
        <Line
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: { text: "2020-09-01T15:30Z - 2020-09-10T17:00Z", display: true },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 100,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: "Actual"
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    display: false
                  },
                  scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: "Forecast"
                  }

                }
              ]
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart3;
```

Comment: Hade you tried removing the spacing from the Grid container?

Comment: please come with a working snippet, if you have a snippet that shows your problem clearly, it will solve your problem much faster compare to come without a snippet, in example, you can create a snippet from code sandbox

Comment: @NishargShah I'm not sure what you mean all relevant code snippets are above

Comment: @khenriksson Yeah I removed spacing but does not effect the white space at the bottom

Comment: creating snippet helps both and save lot of time and its also solve your problem asap because no one have time to add those code into their system and run it and check it whats problem

Comment: @NishargShah I get what you mean but I specified Grid.js was where I had tried to make the height fit the screen but it doesn't - and the picture shows what the code would look like on a server. I added the other code files because its all interrelated within my react app so it may not just be Grid.js where the problem actually is. If that makes sense? I will try code sandbox for future posts however thanks

Comment: great, please try `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: @NishargShah Tried that thanks but doesn't have an effect unfortunately